# CRC function duplication – differ only in pointer vs iterator signature

Tags: c++

This is a CRC function generated by [pyCRC](http://www.tty1.net/pycrc/index_en.html) and changed by me:

> ```
> static inline crc_t crc_update(crc_t          crc, 
>                                char const *   data, 
>                                long long      data_len)
> {
>     while (data_len--) 
>     {
>         crc = (crc_table[(crc ^ *data) & 0xff] ^ (crc >> 8));
>         ++data;
>     }
>     return crc;
> }
> ```

I made an iterator version of it:

```
static inline crc_t crc_update(crc_t                          crc, 
                               std::istreambuf_iterator<char> data, 
                               long long                      data_len)
{
   /* body identical to the above */
}
```

Is there a way I can avoid duplication? (The main purpose of the code is to be fast.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious way is to replace the type that changes with a templated type, like this:

```
template<typename T>
static inline crc_t crc_update(crc_t          crc, 
                               T              data, 
                               long long      data_len)
{
    while (data_len--) 
    {
        crc = (crc_table[(crc ^ *data) & 0xff] ^ (crc >> 8));
        ++data;
    }
    return crc;
}
```

Or in words: put `template<typename T>` in front of the function, and replace all `char const *` with `T`.

There are some details about inserting `typename` [in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024773/odd-error-with-c-class-template) to help the compiler, but those do not apply in this case.

To prevent incorrect usage, one might add some checks to ensure that only 8 bit types can be used. However, that is advanced stuff and not required to answer your question.